# Don't understand theorem $\exists z\in \mathbb{R}\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^+\left[\exists y\in \mathbb{R}(y-x=y/x)\leftrightarrow x\neq z\right]$.

Tags: logic, proof-verification, proof-writing

I am reading a book on proof-writing techniques. One of the main ideas is that whenever you want to prove a statement starting with existential quantifier, you must choose a particular instance of an object, such that what follows is true. It is called "existential instantiation".

There is a theorem in the exercises that I am given to prove.

$\textbf{Theorem:}$ $\exists z \in \mathbb{R} \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^+ \left[ \exists y \in \mathbb{R} (y - x = y / x) \leftrightarrow x \neq z \right] $.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ At this point I am already confused. Do I get it right that in this case I must use existential instantiation and proceed to choose a particular value of $z$, let's say $z_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^+ \left[ \exists y \in \mathbb{R} (y - x = y / x) \leftrightarrow x \neq z_0 \right]$?

Then I move on and choose an arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$ ("universal instantiation").

So now I have to prove $\exists y \in \mathbb{R} (y - x = y / x) \leftrightarrow x \neq z_0$.

($\rightarrow$) Assume $\exists y \in \mathbb{R} (y - x = y / x)$. Then I must prove that $x \neq z_0$. Again, using existential instantiation, I choose a particular $y$, say $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $ (y_0 - x = y_0 / x)$. At this point it gets really interesting. How do I show that $ (y_0 - x = y_0 / x) \rightarrow x \neq z_0$ if the expression on the left does not even have $z_0$?!

($\leftarrow$) I need to prove that $x \neq z_0 \rightarrow \exists y \in \mathbb{R} (y - x = y / x)$. I must show that there does exist a $y$ that works. Consider $y = (x^2 + x) / (x - 1)$. This particular $y$ is going to work. But again, I don't see how that follows from the fact that $x \neq z_0$!

So my idea so far is that this exercise is given to let us understand some point about existential instantiations, and that is exactly the point I don't seem to get. And this tricky $z$ is ruining everything, we could completely throw it away and nothing would have changed.

$\textbf{So my question is:}$ how exactly do we prove this theorem and what am I missing to complete the proof?

Comment: Existential instantiation means you can choose which $z$ and $y$ you choose. You seem to want to prove the theorem for arbitrary $z_0$ or $y_0$. You have to choose the $z_0$ carefully.

Comment: For instance, in your second implication, that value of $y$ is undefined if $x=1$.

Comment: You have to choose your $z$ *before* you move on to the rest of the problem. In other words, you have to look at the statement $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^+ \left[ \exists y \in \mathbb{R} (y - x = y / x) \leftrightarrow x \neq z_0 \right]$ and come up with the answer to the question "what value of $z_0$ makes this statement true?". Once you think you have the right value of $z_0$, then you go on to prove that statement.

Comment: So, ask yourself: "Is it true if $z_0 = 42$? How about if $z_0 = \pi$? What about if $z_0 = -34.923885$?" Keep using your imagination and insight until you hit upon the right $z_0$.

Comment: Only at that point, where you have hit upon the appropriate value of $z_0$, and you've substituted that value of $z_0$ into the statement, do you then go ahead and use universal instantiation to prove the statement $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^+ \left[ \exists y \in \mathbb{R} (y - x = y / x) \leftrightarrow x \neq z_0 \right]$.

Answer (score 2):

To add a bit to the comments: existential instantiation is generally something that you use when you *already* have an existentially quantified sentence (say, in the premises). Here, what you need is to *prove* an existentially quantified sentence. In order to do this, the best way is to *exhibit* the particular $z$ in question. This is easier to see in practice, so I'll prove an easier theorem just to show you what I mean.

Suppose I want to prove, from the field axioms, that $\forall x \forall z \exists y (x = y + z)$ (i.e. that subtraction is possible). So what do I do? I need to work with *arbitrary* numbers, which I'll be able to (in this case) universally generalize, and with a *specific* number that I want to existentially quantify over. Let's go over this in steps.

(1) So let $x$ and $z$ be arbitrary numbers.

(2) By the field axioms, we know that there is a number, called $-z$, such that $z + (-z) = 0$.

(3) So choose $y$ such that $y = -z + x$ (which we know to exist, since addition is well defined according to these axioms);

(4) Now consider $z + y$, which, again, we know to be well defined.

(5) By using simple identity laws, plus associativity, $z + y = z + ((-z) + x)  = (z + (-z)) + x = 0 + x = x$.

(6) Since $x$ and $z$ were arbitrary, for every $x$ and $z$, *there is* a desired $y$ that proves the theorem.

Notice that the crucial step in the above proof is (3), where I deliberately chose a $y$ that I knew would give the desired result. That's generally the trick when your goal is to prove existentially quantified sentences: you don't want to deal with arbitrary objects, but with specifically chosen ones. In your particular case, you have to carefully select a $z$ that will give you the desired result. Obviously, you won't always be able to discover which object is the necessary one; in this case, the only resource we have left to prove an existentially quantified statement is to argue by contradiction (i.e. suppose there is no such $z$; then contradiction ensues).

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to read the sentence as in ordinary language first so that quantifiers are not mind boggling.

The statement is saying that there is a real number z such that

corresponding to each positive real number x, there exists a real number y such that the equation y-x = y/x holds if and only if x does not take the value z.

Since we need to prove (at the most outside level of logical parantheses) existence of such a z, one way of doing so is actually producing a concrete value for z such that the statement is valid.

Now let's look at the rest of the sentence. corresponding to each positive real x, arguing existence of real y , means that for any positive real value of x outside some specified value(s) z, one can solve the equation for y in terms of x.

Equation "y-x = y /x " holds if and only if  "yx-x^2 = y " (multiplying by nonzero x on both sides) if and only if "y(x-1) = x^2 " (after adding x^2 -y on both sides and factoring on left hand side) if and only if "y = x^2 / (x-1)" where division is justified only when x is not equal to 1. But in this final step we have solved for y in terms of x.

In other words we have evaluated (through logical equivalences said in words) that when x is not equal to 1 ( so z = 1) that when y takes the value  x^2 / (x-1) the said equation  holds.

Answer (score 1):

We can try with a simpler example (I'll use only one "direction" of the bi-conditional) :

> $\forall x \in \mathbb N [\exists y \in \mathbb N (x \ne 0 \rightarrow (y < x) )]$.

Here a "rough-cut" proof :

---

Assume : $x \ne 0$

Then, using Peano's axioms :

$x=S(y)$, for some $y$ [where $S$ is the *successor* function].

Again by axioms :

$x=S(y)+0=S(y+0)=y+S(0)$.

Now we can use the *abbreviation* : $y < x \leftrightarrow \exists w (x = y + S(w))$ to conlcude with :

> $y < x$, for some $y$.

Thus, from $x \ne 0 \vdash \exists y (y < x)$, we have :

$x \ne 0 \rightarrow \exists y (y < x)$

and, by properties of quantifiers [$y$ is not free in $x \ne 0$] :

> $\exists y (x \ne 0 \rightarrow (y < x))$.

This is true for $x$ whatever; thus :

> $\forall x [\exists y (x \ne 0 \rightarrow (y < x) )]$.

Only now we can use $\exists$-intro [from : $\varphi(t)$, infer : $\exists x \varphi(x)$, with $0$ as the *term* $t$] to conclude with :

> > $\exists z\forall x [\exists y (x \ne z \rightarrow (y < x) )]$.